# How would distant objects in a contracting universe look?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, redshift

Our current universe is expanding, and distant galaxies are redshifted, with a redshift that increases as the distance to the galaxy increases. After a certain distance, the galaxies move faster than the speed of light, the redshift becomes infinite, and we get a kind of event horizon past which we can't see anything.

Now, how would that look like in a contracting universe?
Would further away galaxies move faster towards us? If so, does that mean light would be blueshifted, and the further you look the more shifted it is? Would there be a point past which galaxies seem to be moving towards us at the speed of light? What would that even look like?

Comment: That's a good question.  I think you'are assuming an infinite universe somehow magically exists, complete with galaxies etc. and has been continuously contracting from an infinite time in the past.  I don't know the answer, but I suspect you end up with the opposite of Olber's paradox and get burnt to a crisp by an infinitely bright gamma-ray sky.

Answer (score 0):

For a long time we would simply see the same as in our universe in reverse. "New" highly redshifted galaxies would appear in the far distance and then start coming towards us, their redshift decreasing with time. The local density would increase slowly, at first, and then ever faster. However, those galaxies that were once far away would never reach us before the local density diverges after the finite collapse time.

The most "interesting" period would probably be around the time when the collapse is  going towards average stellar densities. While there are no large black holes during the early era of our universe as far as we know, there could be hundreds of billions in a re-collapsing version. It is probably a non-trivial astrophysics question what would happen if these galactic black holes would eventually be condensed to an average distance of the size of the solar system, with all the remaining matter at stellar densities. The last couple hours sound like a nightmarish scenario with superheated matter falling into these ever growing black holes and enormous hyper-relativistic jets forming shock waves in this dense matter soup. As soon as the event horizons touch, the black hole mergers would probably drag almost everything into these now galactic mass abysses. It is therefor not clear to me if a re-collapsing universe would look like the early era of an expanding one at all. I very much doubt it.

Comment: Approaching galaxies would be blueshifted, not redshifted. It's not just a movie played backward because the past light cones point in the opposite direction.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about your question as contracting universe will be against 2nd low of thermodynamics, the entropy is decreasing.
Otherwise I think. Your guesses are right just put - sign in **Hubble's law**.
Hope this helps.

Comment: A contracting universe wouldn't be against the 2nd law, it's just what would happen if the universe was dense enough to overcome dark energy and inertia. My point is... that there's definitely something off, for me at least, about an infinitely blueshifted thing.